# Transliterate with iconv() on Windows

Tags: php, windows, locale, iconv

On Linux `iconv()` transliterates umlauts correctly to ASCII according to the current locale setting:

```
$utf8_umlaut_a = 'ä';

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US');
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8_umlaut_a); // Gives 'a'

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE');
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8_umlaut_a); // Gives 'ae', correct
                                                   // in German
```

However, on Windows I can only get `"a` (that is: *double-quote, a*) regardless of the locale set. Apparently on Windows the locales are named "english" and "german", but:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'german');
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8_umlaut_a); // Still gives '"a'
```

Comment: good question, i wonder if exists a way to perform transliteration by language, not generically by charset

Comment: Its an open PHP bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66278

Answer (score -1):

I have solved many UTF-8 related issues by using mb_convert_encoding() and other mb_* functions instead of iconv.